# Docker: Error response from daemon when running a nanoserver container on Windows Server 1903

Tags: docker, containers, daemon

Я пытаюсь запустить контейнер Docker в cmd windows 10 pro с использованием команды:
docker container run -it mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-1903 pwsh.exe

Получаю следующее сообщение об ошибке:
docker: Error response from daemon: hcs::CreateComputeSystem 340bf623299b6badae101f2128b63dc55312560f9a4e6954bfd21fd31fa3529a: The request is not supported.

Такую же ошибку получаю при попытке выполнить команду в powershell. И тот и другой терминалы открываю с правами администратора

По поиску инфы в интернете:

1. Убедился, что все службы Hyper-V включены.
2. Перезагружал компьютер))
3. Версия Docker актуальная.
4. Попытался загрузить другие контейнеры из http://mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-1903 - та же ошибка .
5. Службы VirtualBox и VMware на компьютере отсутствуют.

При попытке запустить через docker descktop получаю:
Failed to run image. (HTTP code 500) server error - container d81c0832cd3fb5e27ed26581b549b3baaebacf7f8a5137da04df088f13d27d49 encountered an error during hcs::System::Start: failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container exited unexpectedly. (0xc0370106)

Информация о моей системе:

- Операционная система: Windows 10 pro 22H2
- Docker version: 4.27.1

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, с чем может быть связана ошибка и как ее исправить.